# How do I make the canvas display the recoloured image instead of the same image?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I had an image of Canada and manually recolored its pixels to shades of blue. I then tried to make a script that would do the same(into red) without me going through all the hassle.

But for some reason, the canvas simply repaints the same image of the blue Canada in Mozilla and Chrome(sometimes not even draws it).
Mozilla says accessing ImageData is a security error. What did I get wrong and how do I fix it?

Snippet right here:

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imgPath = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/Copper_sulfate.jpg/234px-Copper_sulfate.jpg";
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
imgObj.src = imgPath;

imgObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
  map = context.getImageData(0, 0, 234, 240);
  imagedata = map.data;

  for (p = 0; p < imagedata.length; p += 4) {
    imagedata[p] = imagedata[p + 2];
    imagedata[p + 2] = 0;
    imagedata[p + 3] = 255;
  };
  context.putImageData(map, 0, 0);
};
```

```html
<img id="Canada" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/Copper_sulfate.jpg/234px-Copper_sulfate.jpg" />
<canvas id='canvas' width='234px' height='240px'></canvas>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This seems to work for me. Can you post a [mcve] using a boilerplate image as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Comment: I will try to, as soon as I can

Comment: Yeah your snippet works fine for me. I don't see any problem here...

Comment: If it worked to you, does it mean it drew a red version of the image?

Comment: Yep. If you press "run" on the above snippet and scroll down, there's the original blue image with a red one below it.

Comment: Then the problem is that it does not display for me.
There must be something else I am missing

Comment: I don't see any image at all!

Comment: So some people see both images, some see only one, and some don't see any.

Comment: If you aren't seeing an image, it's a request problem, not an algorithm problem with the canvas. You're using a google search image that might be blocked for certain people on certain browsers. Try it now--works for me on IE, Edge, FF and Chrome on Windows and FF on a Ubuntu machine.

Comment: By the way, *always* add `var`, `let` or `const` in front of your variables. Your loop var `p` as well as `map`, `context` and `canvas` are global which can lead so very unusual and difficult to track down bugs.